# Unable to make gray eol character by .vimrc

Tags: vim, colors

I want to have a gray eol character set by

```
set list listchars=tab:>>,trail:$
```

where there are no spaces next to the character ":"

I get **no eol character** for the above code if I use no spaces next to ":".

I get a green trailing character if I use one space at

```
- - tab:[space]>> --
```

although I have not set it up explicitly

such that

[alt text http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/175564/trailingCharacter.png](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/175564/trailingCharacter.png)
*(old code in terminal)*

**How can you make the eol character gray in Vim,** and to make it work again?

Comment: "I get now the following error:
E474: Invalid argument: listchars=tab:»"

It seems that you did write 'set listchars=tab:»' instead of 'set listchars=tab:>>'. The second case is correct, where you have you "greater" signs after the colon. In the first case, you have the "»" sign, which is one character.

Also, as sykora said, you should not write spaces after ">>" and after "trail:". So here is what you should write:

set list listchars=tab:>>,trail:$

Comment: @hcs42: I have now no spaces after >> and $. I get now no E474 -error message, but I get now no trailing character.

Comment: Boy that default blue color is so awful to read.

Comment: The link to the image is broken. Please re-upload to Imgur.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are two highlighting groups: SpecialKey and NonText. The trailing characters you mention belong to the NonText one.

Try something like this (y/pasted):

```
set list
set listchars=eol:$,tab:>-,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<
hi NonText ctermfg=7 guifg=gray
```

Does that work for you, or did I understand the question wrong (quite possible).

Comment: I found that "The "NonText" highlighting will be used for "eol", "extends" and                                                                                                                                 
             "precedes".  "SpecialKey" for "nbsp", "tab" and "trail"."

Comment: @Masi - I don't understand what is it you want exactly. Do you wish to change the color of eol char, or do you wish to set "$" as a trailing character, and change its color ? In your picture in your question, the character in line 27 is not a trailing character, it is an eol char.

Comment: But in that picture you also have trailing characters set to $, so that could be one source of errors.

Comment: Try it like this. First, set "set list" and "set listchars=". Btw, you can always see your listchars with "set listchars?". Now we got it resetted. Now, set your listchars options to something, just make sure every char is different (see my example above), and then set "hi SpecialKey" and "hi NonText" options. That should work. If it starts acting weird, post the results. But it should work.

Comment: @Idigas: You are completely correct. I confused trailing character with eol character. I want the eol character to be in gray. Thank you for pointing that out! -- I set "hi SpecialKey guifg=gray" unsuccessfully.

Comment: @Masi - ok, then you just set "hi NonText guifg=gray" and you're done. (or ctermfg, ... depends on what version of vim you're using, but you probably know that part). Cheers!

Comment: @Idigas: It seems that something in my .vimrc affects the eol character, since the color of eol does not change at all, when I change colors. -- Please, see the following screenshot in iTerm and in Mac's default terminal: http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/175564/eolProblem.png

Comment: @Idigas: I commented out everything else in my .vimrc. The bug cannot be in it.

Comment: @Masi - sorry, took me a while. I was away. I admit, you got me confused a little. Do you perchance load another vimrc from somewhere else (after loading this one) ? What platform are you on anyway ?

Comment: How much colors does your terminal support ?

Comment: @Idigas: I use OS/X and my terminal supports 16 colors.

Comment: @Masi - I've been experimenting a little and I can't reproduce your behaviour. If you try to start vim with an empty vimrc (be careful you don't load some other vimrc in the background), does it show the same behaviour after modifying "set list", "listchars" and "hi NonText" options ? Unfortunatelly, I use WinXP and *nix, and don't have OS/X to exactly try it on that.

Comment: Vim with an empty vimrc can be started (on my platform anyway) with an "-u" parameter.

Comment: @Idigas: You made a crux move. :hi NonText ctermfg=7 works when set inside Vim. It seems that my Vim does not read the line at the startup.

Comment: @Idigas: I found the bug. I had the following command in my .vimrc: hi clear. -- Thank you for your answers!

Comment: `highlight SpecialKey ctermfg=darkgray` and `highlight NonText ctermfg=darkgray` worked for me, on macOS 12.6.

Answer (score 8):

The `trail`, `tab` and `nbsp` listchars use the `SpecialKey` highlight group, so you can use this:

```
highlight SpecialKey ctermfg=8
```

to make the `$` symbol grey. If you have 256 colors enabled, you can use a different shade of grey, like 243, etc.

Comment: The code makes no change for the color of my trailing character. I am not sure why. --debugging-- I added a small code to my original post. I have tried to get your code work with it and without it unsuccessfully.

Comment: I tried it again, works perfectly. Are you sure you're using as many spaces as you have put in your post? eg. Space before , is illegal, etc. At least it's erroring out here.

Comment: This method almost worked for me (Vim 7.3 terminal mode). But it works only when i issue this command on vim prompt, putting it in `vimrc` has no effect

Comment: @Dfr Make sure you don't have `hi clear` or similar later in your vimrc.

Comment: Thank you, now it is working. Also i was using custom coloscheme, so i just edited colorcheme.vim and set `SpecialKey` option there

Comment: `:verbose hi SpecialKey` helps find what script last set the value.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the *eol* to be gray, specify the *eol* suboption of `listchars` instead of *trail*:

```
set list listchars=tab:>>,eol:$
```

*trail* shows the unnecessary whitespace characters at the end of the lines, not the end of lines themselves.

If you want to set the color of *eol*, you have to set the highlighting of the `NonText` group:

```
highlight NonText ctermfg=8 guifg=gray
```

If you specify both `ctermfg` and `guifg`, the highlighting will work both in the GUI and in a terminal.

I have to point out though some shortcomings:

- The highlighting of the tilde characters after the end of the buffer are the
  same as the highlighting of the eol-signs. I think it is not possible to
  separate those; their highlightings are both determined by the highlighting
  of `NonText`. So if you set gray eols, you will be gray tildes.
- On my terminal, `ctermfg=8` makes red and not gray text.